# Youtube Player not defined - multiple YT iframe embeds each with custom Play button (not firing), using $.each to iterate through the embeds

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

I have >1 Youtube embeds on a page, each with a custom Play button but I can't get the custom Play btn working for multiple instances.

I used this [CSS Tricks example](https://css-tricks.com/play-button-youtube-and-vimeo-api/#article-header-id-0) as a starter and it works fine in isolation, but trying to get >1 working - using $each() - isn't happening.

Here's a [**CODEPEN**](https://codepen.io/artcrowned/pen/yLYwKLw) to what I've done so-far.
In the codepen I get the following error msg:

> ReferenceError: YoutubePlayer is not defined

I've referenced an attempt at fixing that, which is since commented out.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Here's the html:

```
<div class="outer">

  <div class="yt-player__outer">
    <div class="yt-player__inner">
      <iframe class="yt-player-item" width="100%" height="auto" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/PAJ1IHT9SVk?enablejsapi=1&html5=1" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <button class="yt-play-btn">PLAY</button>
  </div>

  <div class="yt-player__outer">
    <div class="yt-player__inner">
      <iframe class="yt-player-item" width="100%" height="auto" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/e03DrQmQqak?enablejsapi=1&html5=1" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <button class=".yt-play-btn">PLAY</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the js:

```
// YT API script tag:
let tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/player_api";
let firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

let ytPlayer;

// player container
const ytVidPod = document.getElementsByClassName('yt-player__outer');

const YoutubePlayers = () => {

    $.each(ytVidPod, function() {

        const thisVidPod = $(this);

        // Youtube iframe
        const ytInstance = thisVidPod.find('iframe.yt-player-item');
        // play button
        const ytPlayBtn = thisVidPod.find('.yt-play-btn');

        // TEST the Play btn and yt-iframe are being found:
        ytPlayBtn.on('click', function(){
            ytInstance.toggleClass('HIT');      // this works
        });

        // 1st try at fixing YT Player not defined
        // function loadPlayer() {
        //   window.onYouTubePlayerAPIReady = function() {
        //     onYouTubePlayer();
        //   };
        // }

        function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
            ytPlayer = new YT.Player(
            ytInstance, {
                events: {
                    // call when player is ready
                    'onReady': onPlayerReady
                }
            });
        }

        function onPlayerReady(event) {
            ytPlayBtn.on('click', function() {
                ytPlayer.playVideo();   // NOPE
            });
        }

    }); // END $.each

};

if(ytVidPod){
    YoutubePlayer();
    console.log(ytVidPod);  // logs the players
}
```

Comment: Typo at YoutubePlayer**s** and `thisVidPod.find('yt-play-btn');` should be `thisVidPod.find('.yt-play-btn');`

Comment: @Viney thanks, typo fixed, issue still happening though so am continuing ...